# Integrate the differential equation of a simple rate equation

Tags: calculus, integration

Could somebody please show me how to integrate the following:

$dA/dt = -kA$

I'm told that the answer is:

$A(t) = A(0)e^-kt$

but I do not know why. Could you be explicit in your answer and explain precisely why it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dA}{A} = \int(-k)dt
$$
(If you don't trust the blithe movement of $dt$ to the right like that, consider that $\frac{dA}{dt} = \left( \frac{dt}{dA} \right)^{-1}$ and work with 
$$
\frac{dt}{dA} = -\frac{1}{kA}
$$ which integrates to $t = -\frac{1}{k}\ln A$, but as long as you are taking a math course, you might as well get used to carefully working with infinitessimals like this.)

So 
$$\int \frac{dA}{A} = \int(-kt)dt \Longrightarrow \ln A = -kt + C 
 \Longrightarrow A(t) = e^C e^{-kt}
$$
where $C$ is some arbitrary constant of integration.  (You never have to put the constants in on both sides, because they would subtract to just get one constant.

So how do we figure out the value of $C$?  Well, if we know the value of $A$ at $x=0$ is some value $A(0)$ then
$$
e^C e^0 = A(0) \Longrightarrow e^C = A(0)$$

and the answer is then 
$$
A(t) = A(0) e^{-kt}
$$

Comment: The only thing I don't understand here is the decision to use the natural log? Could you expand a little? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your equation in the form
$\frac{dA}{A}=-kdt$
solving this we obtain $\ln(A)=-kt+C$ if $A>0$

Answer (score 0):

$$A'=-kA \iff \frac{A'}{A}=-k \stackrel{\int \mathrm{d}t}{\iff} \log |A|=-kt+c \iff A=e^{-kt+c}=e^{-kt}e^c\stackrel{e^c=A_0}{\iff} A=A_0 e^{-kt}$$